# What does a local maximum under 1 in a two-point correlation function mean?

Tags: scattering, diffraction, correlation-functions, liquid-state

Two-point correlation functions like the radial distribution function (real space) and the structure factor $S(q)$ (reciprocal space) give information about correlations in a (typically) fluid material relative to an ideal gas. What does a local maximum in one of these functions that is under 1 (in $y$) mean?

My thinking is that it would suggest that, although the intensity of the correlations there is a local maximum, the structure in that region is still not well correlated because the RDF (or $S(q)$) $< 1$. Does that same conclusion apply for the RDF as for $S(q)$? I'm having trouble conceptualizing this.

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that the radial distribution function $g(r)$ and the structure factor $S(q)$ give information about correlations, they do not coincide completely with the correlation function in real or in the reciprocal space. In the ideal gas limit (uncorrelated limit), both functions are constant and equal to $1$. Therefore, the correlation function in real and reciprocal space are respectively $h(r)=g(r)-1$, and $H(q)=S(q)-1$.

Negative values of correlation functions are allowed, while $g(r)$ and $S(q)$ must be positive. A negative value of $h(r)$ or $H(q)$ indicates an anti-correlation. The interpretation of a negative local maximum of these functions directly derives from their physical meaning.

In the case of $h(r)$, local maxima define regions of distances where the probability of finding a particle, once one has been fixed at the origin, is higher than in the neighborhood, although *below* the completely random case.

In the case of the structure factor, the correlation is between density fluctuations of wavevector $q$. A local peak at $q_1$ in the reciprocal space, independently on the sign, is always a signal of some short-range periodicity of about $\frac{2 \pi}{q_1}$. However, the relative contribution of such short-range periodicity to the scattering cross-section may be larger (positive peak and correlation) or smaller (negative peak and anti-correlation) than the ideal gas contribution.

Notice that the link with scattering cross-section easily explains the asymmetry between positive and negative values: a value of $H(q)<-1$ would imply a *negative* scattered intensity at some direction from the sample. For a different but similar reason, also values of $h(r)<-1$ are forbidden: they would imply regions of *negative* average number of pairs.

Comment: +1 Thank you. Just to be clear, a negative local maximum in $H(q)$ indicates an anti-correlation with periodicity of $2\pi/q_{1}$? I don't have a good feel for what an anti-correlation represents -- not the presence of local ordering?

Comment: @user2561523 I'll try to clarify this point with an addition to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am still trying to understand this. As an example, at low-$q$ in $H(q)$, the length scale of the box will show up. The intensity of the peak will be lower than 0, so, as you say, the density fluctuations must be anti-correlated with respect to an ideal gas. Does that imply anything about ordering vs. randomness of such anti-correlated features?